# Connect external hardware to android tablet

Tags: android, serial-port, hardware, tablet

Im developing an application for a manufacturing plant. They want to connect a scale, printer and meter counter to an android tablet.

They use rs232 ports.

Im planning on using the galaxy view tablets that have a Micro Usb port, then hook that up to usb hub and then use a rs232 converter.

My question is will this be able to communicate to the tablet? At least show the raw values and will it know its 3 separate pieces of hardware?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem but only part of your problem here:
[Connecting external hardware to Android Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419507/connecting-external-hardware-to-android-phone)

You need to ask those hardware manufacturer to send you the Android driver to include in your Android app. It will run on some phone but may not work on all phone. Most software developer will refuse to provide support for Android as there are so many manufacturers and possibly compliance issue. Your best bet will be to ask the hardware manufacturer which phone/tablet they have tested the device on. In any case you still need a hardware driver like the one for windows.